# Any deep learning models for instance classification in an image, rather than bounding box?

Tags: classification, instance

I need to classify pixel-wise instances in an image. Most object detection models, e.g., RetinaNet, R-CNNs, only detect bounding box. In my case the non-instance region in a bounding box can be significantly different from the instance. Even though the mask R-CNN model still does object classification based on the bounding box area. Does anybody know what model should I use? I guess Facebook's MultiPathNet probably works, but I am not using Linux. Are there any other models? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds that you're looking for instance-level segmentation (as a short term for the long explanation).

Mask R-CNN sounds just right for the job.
It does instance-level segmentation based on the region proposals, not only bounding boxes.
The segmentation is a binary mask of the instance. The classification is made by a dedicated branch.

Comment: Thank you. But what I am looking for is instance-level classification, not only segmentation. Mask R-CNN does classification based on the bounding boxes, even though the mask generation is at instance level.

Comment: Could you stress the difference? You have a a per-instance mask and classification.

Comment: Yes, I do have a per-instance mask and classification. The reason why I wanna instance-level classification is that most instances have strange shapes such that the bounding box of an instance contains large non-instance regions, and the characteristics of the non-instance regions are quite different from instance. Thus, I think using bounding box might not be accurate for instance classification.

Comment: By "You have", I meant the output of Mask R-CNN. Both the segmentation, BB regression and classification use about the same features, which are object-related features, by which you can infer which object this is, and where it is located. The fact that the classification uses features which are not strictly inside the object is actually good for the model, since many times context helps to better classify the object. In any case, the features are supposed to represent the most relevant features to infer the above tasks, so the model learns which features to use and how to weight them.

Comment: Thank you. I see your point now, and you are right. However, in my case, e.g., for road condition classification (e.g., snowy or not), road is often long and thin in the image, such that the bounding box of road contains a large non-road area, which has quite different conditions than the road. For example, road can be dry while non-road region is fully snowy. So I am looking for an object classification model which uses features representing the road, rather than non-road regions.

Comment: Maybe the model based on bounding box, e.g., mask-rcnn, can still learn most relevant feathers of road, but I am not quite sure about it.